# How do I tell Windows to keep internal disks offline?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, automount

I don't want Windows to bring disks that are internal online automatically.

Windows To Go has such a feature that can be set via an XML file; however, it requires jumping through a lot of hoops, and it's not clear how to enable it for an existing system. However, when enabled, it results in Disk Management saying:

> The disk is offline because of policy set by an administrator.

I was wondering how to enable this manually for an existing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an online system, run `DiskPart`, then type in:

```
 SAN Policy=OfflineInternal
```

Other options are [available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/winpe-storage-area-network--san--policy) too; type in

```
Help SAN
```

for help.

For an offline system, you can edit the following registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\partmgr\Parameters]
"SanPolicy"=dword:00000004
```